# Possible to skip a class if a method fails inside that class using TestNG?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

Possible to skip a class if a method fails inside that class using TestNG?

1. We have x2 classes: classX and ClassY
2. Lets say method2 of 5 in classX fail's > methods 3, 4, 5 are in turn then skipped.
3. Is it possible then to still execute classY even though classX has had methods which have failed?

thanks

Comment: This should help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945769/how-to-disable-testng-test-based-on-a-condition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable testng test based on a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945769/how-to-disable-testng-test-based-on-a-condition)