# Maven run tests in some groups

Tags: java, maven, automation, testng

I have got such 3 groups (3 tests) in my testng project code, for example:

```
groups = {"iOS", "Android", "Sync"})

groups = {"iOS", "Sync"})

groups = {"Android", "Sync"})
```

How can I run all tests which contain some groups, for example: "Android" **AND** "Sync"?

If I run:

```
mvn clean test -PAndroid -Dgroups=Android,Sync
```

I will run all 3 tests because this syntax works:  "Android" **OR** "Sync", but I need only the first and the third test to be run.

Comment: You will have to use annotation transformer for conditional enable disable of test https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945769/how-to-disable-testng-test-based-on-a-condition

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try a tag expression `Android&Sync`

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-tag-expressions

This might require some single or double quotes on your command line

(perhaps `"-Dgroups=Android&Sync"` - though I havent tried it.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using by creating the profiles of your groups in maven.

or

You it like this- Dgroups='Andriod', -Dgroups='sync'

Answer (score 0):

Another way is, exclude `IOS`  group, use this (note excluded vs exclude).  [here is docs](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#excludedGroups)

```
mvn test -DexcludedGroups==IOS
```