# Selenium Automation: Skip execution of test based on a condition in @BeforeMethod

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

My code is like this:

```
@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod() {
   url= GetUrlBasedOnParameter(parameter);
   if(is.empty(url)) {
      SkipTest();
   } else {
      ExecuteTest();
   }
}
```

What condition can I use in `SkipTest()` so that without adding any additional parameters in `@Test` annotation, I can skip the test?

FYI: I tried `driver.quit()` and `driver.close()` but the `@Test` annotation is still executed.

Comment: Are `@Test` and `@BeforeMethod` JUnit annotations?

Comment: TestNG annotations

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable TestNG test based on a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945769/how-to-disable-testng-test-based-on-a-condition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TestNG, you can use

```
throw new SkipException("message");
```

So, your `@BeforeMethod` could look like

```
@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod() {
   url= GetUrlBasedOnParameter(parameter);
   if(is.empty(url)) {
      throw new SkipException("URL is empty");
   } else {
      ExecuteTest();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The browser was still active so I added ```quit()``` method before the exception call.