# How to skip test if its taking time more than certain amount of time in TestNG?

Tags: java, testing, testng, web-api-testing, testng-eclipse

I am having API test suite where few tests taking a great amount time causing test suite to run more than 5-6+ hrs.
Is there any way to skip certain tests which exceeds run time for that particular test in TestNG.

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945769/how-to-disable-testng-test-based-on-a-condition) might help you. You'll have to identify and "mark" the long-running tests beforehand as TestNG cannot know how much time they take before they were running.

Answer (score 0):

First you implement `IInvokeMethodListener` where you do:

```java
@Override
public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult){
  if(testResult.getThrowable() instanceof ThreadTimeoutException){
    testResult.setStatus(ITestResult.SKIP);
  }
}
```

Say you implemented it in `MyImpl` class. Then you could have:

```java
@Listeners({MyImpl.class})
public class MyTest {

  @Test(timeOut = 1)
  public void test(){
    // Do long task that takes more than 1 ms
    // The test will be skipped
  }

}
```